# How to combine multiple arrays into one?

Tags: php, arrays

```
Json string : $return ='{"contract_id":["33"],"group":["1","2"],"item":["1","No items found"],"harga_1":["4","1"],"qty":["2","2"],"amount":["8","2"],"action":"test"}';

$data = json_decode($return, true);
var_dump($data['item']);
array (size=2)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string 'No items found' (length=14)
var_dump($data['group']);
output:
array (size=2)


 0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '2' (length=1)
```

As you see each attribute in my JSON array carries array. SO how do I combine the first value of all arrays into one single array and the second value of all into another array? Also how to extract each value like $data['?'] after that.

I want to insert into database all the items for one ID and then followed by next ID's items. How to arrange the array in such a way please?

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
$array1 = array("ID"=>"33","group" => "ef4", "item" => "apple", "harga" => "56".....);
$array2 = array("ID"=>"33","group" => "rfrf4", "item" => "a45erf4e", "harga" => "54".....);
```

Comment: What is the desired result, what are you getting, what have you tried?

Comment: @Naruto, I've updated the desired output in my post. Also, I've tried with array_merge_recursive and array_combine

Comment: `"item" => "apple"` where did the `apple` come from? actually i don see how you get from the `$result` to the desired output

Comment: But I think array_intersect_key would help but I'm not sure how to do it for multiple arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP function [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
<?php

//JSON
$json  ='{"contract_id":["33"],"group":["A","B"],"item":["A1","BNo items found"],"harga_1":["A4","B1"],"qty":["A2","B2"],"amount":["A8","B2"],"action":"test"}';
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// Contract
$contractId = array_shift($data); // [33]   

$firstRow = array_column($data, 0);
$secondRow = array_column($data, 1);

/* result:
 *
 * firstRow => array("A","A1","A4","A2","A8")
 * secondRow => array("B","BNo items found","B1","B2","B2")
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example  with multisort.

```
<?php 
        error_reporting(0);
         $multiArray = array( 
                    1,9,3,
                    array(90,20,70),        
                    'a',
                    'x',
                    'p',
                    array("name" => "Defg"), 
                    array("name" => "Abcd"),
                    array("name" => "Eefg"), 
                    array("name" => "Fbcd"),
                    array(9,2,8)
                   );



     $length=count($multiArray);

    array_multisort($multiArray[3], SORT_DESC,SORT_NUMERIC);
    array_multisort($multiArray[11], SORT_ASC,SORT_NUMERIC);

    sort($multiArray);
    var_dump($multiArray);
    $tmp = array(); 
    foreach($multiArray as &$ma) 
   {
     $tmp[] = &$ma["name"];
   } 
    echo "<br>";

         //array_multisort($tmp, SORT_DESC,$multiArray);  

             foreach($multiArray as &$ma)
      {
        "<br>" . $ma["name"] ;
       }     

     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode('{"contract_id":["33"],"group":["1","2"],"item":["1","No items found"],"harga_1":["4","1"],"qty":["2","2"],"amount":["8","2"],"action":"test"}', true);
$values = array( 'contract_id' , 'group' , 'item' , 'harga_1' , 'qty' , 'amount' );
$arrays = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($data['item']); $i++){
    $arrays[$i] = array();
    foreach($values as $value){
        $arrays[$i][$value] = isset($data[$value][$i]) ? $data[$value][$i]: $data[$value][0];
    }
}
var_dump($arrays);
```

The arrays should then be stored in the `$arrays` variable.

Example output:

```
$arrays = array (
  0 => array (
    'contract_id' => '33',
    'group' => '1',
    'item' => '1',
    'harga_1' => '4',
    'qty' => '2',
    'amount' => '8',
  ),
  1 => array (
    'contract_id' => '33',
    'group' => '2',
    'item' => 'No items found',
    'harga_1' => '1',
    'qty' => '2',
    'amount' => '2',
  ),
)
```